# Python, how to make a boolean value equal to True whilst it's in a class that's actually an attribute in another class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, attributes, boolean

I want to make `is_admin=False` become `is_admin=True` in the Privilege class so I can get the `print(_user_privilege)` to work but I do not know how. I know I have to call it through an instance that first calls the User class and then the Privilege class through it's attribute and then change the `is_admin=False` into `is_admin=True` but I do not know how to specifically do that. So can any of you help me? Thanks!

```
class Privileges:

    def __init__(self, is_admin=False):
        self.user_privileges = ["can add post", "can delete post", "can ban user"]
        self.is_admin = is_admin

    def show_privileges(self):
        print()
        if self.is_admin:
            for user_privilege in self.user_privileges:
                print(_user_privilege)
        else:
            print("Sorry but you are not the Admin." +
                "\nYou have limited privileges.")

class User:

    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, address, phone_number):
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.full_name = first_name + " " + last_name
        self.address = address
        self.phone_number = phone_number
        self.privileges = Privileges()
```

I want to make user_1 be admin but not user_2:

```
user_1 = User('Nebojsa', 'Kukic', 'A box under the bridge', 353838935494)


user_2 = User("Siobhan", "O'Neill", "66 The Hermitage", 353831681859)
```

Comment: `user_1.is_admin = True` is the most direct way.

Comment: It does not work

Comment: That would be `user_1.privileges.is_admin = True`

Answer (score -1):

`user_1.privileges.is_admin = True`